# Xfce themes look ugly after HDMI cable is unplugged

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce, hdmi

I sometimes connect my laptop to an external monitor with an HDMI cable, and when I later unplug the cable, it causes a problem with the graphical theme in Xubuntu (14.04).

The window panes, panel, buttons etc. look ugly, and I am unable to change the theme by going to `Settings Manager -> Appearance -> Style` (I mean the style is on Greybird, as it should be, but it doesn't change when I click on different styles). This only seems to happen sometimes after I unplug the HDMI cable (not every time).

Screenshot of ugly appearance:
[image: Ugly windows]

Screenshot of normal appearance:
[image: Normal windows]

The only way I can fix it is to log out and back in again, after which the appearance is back to normal. I assume something is crashing (gtk?). Can anyone explain what might cause this, or how I could track down the cause?

Edit: I use xmonad as a window manager, and restarting xmonad doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: The current gtk theme is propagated by the xfce settings daemon, `xfsettingsd`. It is most probably crashed. Restart it with `xfsettingsd &`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try as soon as I can make the problem happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need recompile `xfce4-settings` with this patch:

http://bug-attachment.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=5681

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1308105

See associated bug report:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11107

Comment: Recompiling xfce4-settings with the patch seems to have fixed it properly, thanks. If others don't want to recompile, as a short-term fix restarting xfsettingsd also worked.

Answer (score 3):

I used to see problems similar to this on old Gnome 2 while playing with compiz, the window manager would need to be restarted sometimes, logging out & back in works, or restarting the window manager might work too. Xubuntu / XFCE uses the `xfwm4` window manager, and it's got an option `--replace` that might work. Try:

```
xfwm4 --replace &
```

in a terminal window & see. I just tried it on my linux mint xfce and it seems to work, though I didn't have any problems so it just flickers the screen & then looks about the same. And running it  without the & keeps it in the terminal foreground, a ctrl-Z suspended the window manager and seemed to mess things up pretty good, but a kill -CONT from another console (ctrl-alt-F5) got it going again.

Running it in an ALT-F2 "Launch" window might be best.

And like aquaherd's comment mentions, restarting `xfsettingsd` might work, it's got a `--replace` option too so I'd try:

```
xfsettingsd --replace &
```

It seems to work good without needing the `&` at the end, probably telling a daemon to run in the background is redundant? With all the different desktop environments, window managers, and settings programs it's hard to keep track.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I use xmonad as a window manager. Restarting xmonad doesn't help, but I guess I could try switching back to xfwm4 then back to xmonad again.

Comment: xmonad might have some other options like replace or restart, but if restarting it doesn't work then I'm not sure what else it might be. If switching to xfwm4 and immediately back to xmonad works that may be just as easy, would run 2 lines instead of just one.

Comment: Or maybe it's more a display problem, try going to the settings Display where you chose the monitor & resolution & refresh rate, change the refresh or resolution & then change them back & see if that resets things?

Comment: I'm afraid changing the display settings didn't seem to help. Thanks though.

Comment: I ran `xfsettingsd --replace &` and after plugging in my monitor I got the following exception: https://gist.github.com/jc00ke/6efaf24fa67a4df2d7e9

At least now I know what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

I often hit this issue. To avoid crashing the Xfce theme (and getting the ugly buttons, etc.), I *always* first disable the external monitor output in `Settings > Display` and only *then* I physically unplug the cable. But this ugly workaround may fail at times.

If you have already experienced the ugly themes, this means that your `xfsettingsd` has crashed. You can easily revert from the ugly theme to the usual desktop appearance settings simply by restarting the daemon in a terminal:

```
xfsettingsd
```

And if this happens often enough (as, for instance, with 4.11.3), then you may want to define a launcher on your panel that will (re-)start the daemon:

[image]

For more details check the [upstream bug report](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11107).